# Is $\Phi^{-1}(\frac{n}{n+1})$ an unbiased estimator of the maximum of $n$ draws from the probability distribution of $\Phi$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a continuous probability distribution $\mathcal{D}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with cdf $\Phi$ and let $X_1,\dots,X_n\sim\mathcal{D}$ be iid random variables.
Then I have the following conjecture: $$\mathbb{E}\left(\max_iX_i\right)=\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$

Can someone tell me whether this is true indeed or not?

I conducted several Monte Carlo Simulations and found that it seems to hold for all continuous distributions, but I have no idea how to prove this rigorously myself and I also could not find a relevant theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intuition you have this is due to the following fact:

1. As $X$ is continuous, we know that $X \sim \Phi^{-1}(U)$ where $U \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$
2. $\Phi^{-1}$ is monotonic increasing (in fact strictly when $X$ is continuous) and thus
   $$ \max_i X_i \sim \max_i\Phi^{-1}(U_i) = \Phi^{-1}\left(\max_i U_i\right) $$
3. $\displaystyle \max_i U_i$ has a Beta distribution with the expectation
   $$ E\left[\max_i U_i\right] = \frac {n} {n+1}  $$

So combining all together, taking expectation from the result 2, we have

$$ E\left[\max_i X_i\right] = E\left[\Phi^{-1}\left(\max_i U_i\right)\right]$$

It is tempted to move the expectation inside $\Phi^{-1}$; However we know that in general they are not equal due to Jensen's inequality:

$$ E\left[\Phi^{-1}\left(\max_i U_i\right)\right] \neq 
\Phi^{-1}\left(E\left[\max_i U_i\right]\right) = 
\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac {n} {n+1}\right)$$

Equality holds only when $\Phi^{-1}$ is linear, i.e. back to the uniform distribution case.

Comment: We have $\beta=\max_iU_i\sim \mathrm B(n,1)$, thus $E=E[\Phi^{-1}(\beta)]=\int_0^1nb^{n-1}\Phi^{-1}(b)\mathrm db$, substitute $b=\Phi(x)$, so $\mathrm d b=\phi(x)\mathrm d x$, and $E=\int_{-\infty}^\infty n(\Phi(x)^{n-1}x\phi(x)\mathrm dx=E[nX_1\Phi(X_1)^{n-1}]$ assuming for simplicity that we have a pdf $\phi$ for $\Phi$. Recall the single big jump principle, notice the upper bound $nE[X_1]$, tight for $n=1$ - looks good.

Answer (score 4):

With $n=1$, your question becomes "is the mean equal to the median?"  The answer is "not necessarily, no," and there's no reason it would become true for larger values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is true for iid uniform distributions, in particular $U(0,1)$ where the density for the maximum is $nx^{n-1}$ and so both sides are $\frac{n}{n+1}$, but in general is not correct for other distributions.

Just as a simple counterexample, suppose $n=2$ and $X_1, X_2$ are i.i.d. standard normal distributions. Then you can show theoretically that $\mathbb{E}\left(\max\limits_iX_i\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\approx 0.5642$ and confirm this with simulation (e.g. in R)

```
cases <- 10^7
set.seed(2023)
X1 <- rnorm(cases, 0, 1)
X2 <- rnorm(cases, 0, 1)
maxX <- ifelse(X1>X2, X1, X2)
mean(maxX)
# 0.5639885
```

while $\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac23\right) \approx 0.4307$, substantially lower, confirmable from the same simulation using

```
quantile(c(X1, X2), 2/3)
# 0.4304617
```